# Teamcity rerun specific failed unstable tests

Tags: testing, build, teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I have Teamcity 7.1 and around 1000 tests. Many tests are unstable and fail randomly. Even a single test fails the whole build fails and to run a new build takes 1 hour.

So I would like to be able to configure Teamcity to rerun failed tests within the same build a specific number of time. Any success for a test should be considered as success, not a failure. Is it possible?

Also now is tests in some module fail Teamcity does not proceed to the next module. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

With respect, I think you might have this problem by the wrong end. A test that randomly fails is not providing you any value as a metric of deterministic behavior. Either fix the randomness (through use of mocks, etc.) or ignore the tests.

Comment: It involves a lot of asynchronous complex staff. Fail probability is very low and almost never fails locally. But with high number of tests failing probability of the whole build gets much higher.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to I'd put loops round some of your test code and catch say 5 failures before throwing the exception as a 'genuine' failure. Something like this C# example would do...

```
    public static void TestSomething()
    {
        var counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                // add test code here...
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception) // catch more specific exception(s)...
            {
                if (counter == 4)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

While I appreciate the problems that can arise with testing asych code, I'm with @JohnHoerr on this one, you really need to fix the tests.

Comment: It is ugly, then I would need to make a list of frequently failing tests and patch the code of them.

Comment: There's no denying its ugliness! I can't think of a way you can get failing tests to be re-run by TC, this may be the easiest way to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Rerun failed tests feature is part of Maven Surefire Plugin, if you execute `mvn -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=2 test`
then tests will be run until they pass or the number of reruns has been exhausted.

Of course, `-Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount` can be used in TeamCity or any other CI Server.

See:
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html